# How to make a user can only delete or modify thier own Post using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

How can I make a user can only delete or modify their own post.

I can successfully add a post with the user id who's logging and I can delete or modify a post but i want to make sure that the post can be modified or deleted by the specific user who add it.

Here is my function modify post in the controller

```
public function edit(Request $request, Posts $post, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $id): Response
    {
        // $post= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Posts::class)->find($id);
        // $resultat=$this->getUser()->getPosts();
        // $resultat->contains($post);

        // if (!($resultat ==true))
        // {
        //     return $this->json(['code' => 403, 'error' => 'Vous devez être connecté !'], 403);
        // }

        $user = $this->getUser();
        if ($post->isPostedByUser($user))
        {
            return $this->json(['code' => 403, 'error' => 'c est votre post  !'], 403);
        }


        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('posts_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('blog/edit.html.twig', [
            'post' => $post,
            'postform' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

And this is the function I use to see if this post is posted by the current user in the entity Posts.php

```
    public function isPostedByUser(User $user): bool
    {
        
            if ($this->getUser()->getPosts() === $user) {
                return true;
            }
        

        return false;
    }
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Why do you call getPosts()?

Comment: Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: The proper way to do this is by using voter: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this, the first is to do the check directly in the `method`, the second is to use the symfony tools, namely `Voter`.

**1.Way of checking in a method**

```
public function edit(Request $request, Posts $post, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $id): Response
{
 if($post->getUser() != $this->getUser()){  // $post->getUser() or another method that returns the user of your post
 return $this->json(['code' => 403, 'error' => 'c est votre post  !'], 403);
 }

 // some you action

}
```

**2.Variant using symfony Voter**

*Create PostVoter in Security folder*

```
// src/Security/PostVoter.php

class PostVoter extends Voter
{

    const EDIT = 'edit';
    protected function supports(string $attribute, $subject): bool
    {
        if (!$subject instanceof Posts) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute(string $attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }
        /** @var Posts $post */
        $post = $subject;
        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::EDIT:
                return $this->canEdit($post, $user);
        }
        throw new \LogicException('This code should not be reached!');
    }

    private function canEdit(Posts $post, User $user): bool
    {
        return $user === $post->getUser(); // $post->getUser() or another method that returns the user of your post
    }
}
```

*Add to the top of your edit method a check against the newly created PostVoter*

```
public function edit(Request $request, Posts $post, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $id): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('edit', $post); // here we connect the check PostVoter 
  
    // some you action
}
```

---

If you chose option 2, then [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) is more information from the official documentation